# URL names and folders

Tags: url, directory

Can someone tell me how I can make it so my webpage doesn't say 
www.website.com/Contact/contact.html
but would just say
www.website.com/Contact/

like this page does

http://www.trainingunlimited.com.au

Thanks

Comment: The solution depends on the type of webserver you are running. Please provide more information on what your setup is and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Also, in general, most webservers will serve the file `index.html` by default. So if the `Contact` directory has a file in it named `index.html`, chances are the url `www.website.com/Contact/` will server `Contact/index.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contact.html page should be renamed as index.html

Please, try!

Susy.